# pci simple communication controller driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, pci, hp-laserjet

I have a HP laserJet P1102. When I want to install its driver it seems that it need to pci simple communication controller be installed. How to install that pci simple communication controller for my Win 7 32-bit please?
The only error in my device manager window is that the pci simple communication controller is not installed. When I plug the USB of that printer it wants to install the pci simple communication controller but it can't!
From "dxdiag" I found that my system manufacturer is "ECS" and the system model is "945p /pl-A"

After appearing these, no change occur even after waiting for a long time!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PCI Simple Communication Controller often is an onboard modem and should not interfere with installing the printer.

Installing the printer requires additional software. You can download these from www.hp.com. Search for your printer there and download the drivers. Then run the setup.exe and when it asks you to plugin the usb controller do so.

Also, in cases like these, it actually helps if you read the manual that comes with the printer. The drivers should also be on the driverdisk.

Comment: I have the cd driver. When executing the setup.exe in some point it wants to install the pci simple communication controller but it fails (although I have plugged the USB of that printer into my PC). Now I think the only way is to first install the pci simple communication controller. I also downloaded that driver from hp website but it same as my CD.

Comment: Thats odd. Try installing your motherboard's chipset drivers again, then reboot, then try to run the setup from the cd or download again. Also make sure you do not have the usb plugged when running the setup. Setup should present you with instructions on doing so.

Comment: I installed the chipset again and ran the setup but no change. The messages are shown in question (I updated it). And also please have a look at here when I mentioned the problem in this forum: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/339307-pci-simple-communication-controller.html

Comment: Indeed, I was installing that printer on a PC running win 7 and I didn't succeed to install. So after that I tried that printer on my own PC which is running win 7 and also I've installed VMware on it and XP on that VMware. I first tried to install that printer on my win 7 host (I have not any dial-up modem on my motherboard and therefore don't need to install that pci driver and also my device manager in fine without any yellow mark). But again I couldn't to success to install that printer on my win 7!

Comment: So I tried to try the XP (which was on VMware) and after turning that XP on I could install and also use of that printer!:) Now, what do you guys think of this issue please? You think the problem is to do with the 7 OS, that pci driver which was not installed or something else. Thank you all.